# Invalid identifier when using left outer join in SQL

Tags: sql

I get this error for the below code.

> Invalid identifier

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT 
    subjects.neptuncode AS "neptuncode",
    subjects.subjectname AS "subjectname",
    enrollments.examdate AS "examdate"
FROM 
    subjects, enrollments
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    enrollments ON enrollments.subject = subjects.subject_ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(enrollments.enrollmentdate) = 1
ORDER BY  
    subjects.neptuncode, subjects.subjectname, enrollments.examdate;
```

Comment: You should explain what you want to do, given that your query has multiple errors.  A database tag is also helpful.

Comment: enrollments
LEFT OUTER JOIN enrollments ...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
FROM subjects, enrollments
```

to

```
FROM subjects
```

You shouldn't mix the old style of joins (comma delimited) and explicit joins. Really you shouldn't use comma delimited joins as they were essentially replaced many, many years ago.

Comment: You can, but not on the same table without proper aliases (and you shouldn't be using implicit joins anyway, since explicit joins are a part of ANSI-SQL for almost 30 years now...)

Comment: IMHO one shouldn't mix old comma-syntax joins with any other query that contains characters. :-)

Comment: Just a pedantic comment: some databases allow you to mix old & new style joins. It's confusing to me, and my take is they shouldn't be allowed. But they do.

Comment: @TheImpaler, the old style comma separated joins are still in the SQL standard, can't really be removed... But don't use them when writing new code!

Answer (score 1):

> `FROM subjects, enrollments`

There's your problem. 
Change that to `FROM subjects` - problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT s.neptuncode, s.subjectname, MAX(e.examdate) as "examdate"
FROM subjects s JOIN
     enrollments e
     ON e.subject = s.subject_ID 
GROUP BY s.neptuncode, s.subjectname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY s.neptuncode, s.subjectname;
```

This returns the exam date for subjects that have only one enrollee.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is not needed.  Your `HAVING` clause suggests that you want exactly one match.
- You should be using `GROUP BY`; the `HAVING` presupposes that you want to aggregate.
- There is no need to include the exam date in the `ORDER BY`, because there is only one row per neptun code and subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got the idea. But how can I list the codes(neptuncode) and names of all subjects(subjectname) in case of those subjects, for which any of the students registered for the first time, list exam date for this condition.